# Changing inline color with viewBag

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

```
@model MSDiary.Models.Saldo
<h3>O seu saldo actual: <span style="color:@ViewBag.color">@obtemSaldo()</span></h3>

@functions 
{
    HtmlString obtemSaldo()
    {
        decimal saldo = 0;
        if (Model != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in Model.Despesas)
            {
                saldo -= item.DespesaValor;
            }
            foreach (var item in Model.Rendimentos)
            {
                saldo += item.RendimentoValor;
            }
            Model.valor = saldo;
            if(saldo < 0)
            {
                ViewBag.color = "red";
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.color = "green";
            }
        }
        return new HtmlString(saldo.ToString());
    }
}
```

I wanted based on the value of the saldo that means balance, get the red when the balance is <0 and green when > 0 i tryed to use the viewBag to set the color based on the result of the balance and then set it up where the function is called, but it isnt working, if someone can give me a tipe i appreciate :)

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the color attribute before value is assigned to `ViewBag`.
Try writing your `<h3>` tag after `@functions`, like below:

```
@functions {
// your content
}

<h3>O seu saldo actual: <span style="color:@ViewBag.color">@obtemSaldo()</span></h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by myself this way:

```
@model MSDiary.Models.Saldo



@helper obtemSaldo()
{
    decimal saldo = 0;
    if (Model != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in Model.Despesas)
        {
            saldo -= item.DespesaValor;
        }
        foreach (var item in Model.Rendimentos)
        {
            saldo += item.RendimentoValor;
        }
        Model.valor = saldo;
        if(saldo < 0)
        {
            ViewBag.color = "red";
        <p style="color:red">@saldo</p>
}
else
{
    ViewBag.color = "green";
   <p style="color:green">@saldo</p>
}
}

}

<h3>O seu saldo actual: <span>@obtemSaldo()</span></h3>
```